# How to Enable a Disabled JLabel by an argument (Java Swing)

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

So I am creating this game about Game of Thrones and I have a map. To finish the game, you need to answer the first round first before you can proceed to another round. I set a Tool Tip on my disabled jLabels (because all of my buttons are customized) saying "You can't access this yet" on my event Mouse Entered. So if I already enabled it, I thought I should just make an if-else argument but it seems that I have an error with that. Please help me I really don't know what to do :(

```
private void jLabelTargaryenMouseEntered(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                             
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    if (jLabelTargaryen.setEnabled(false)){
        jLabelTargaryen.setToolTipText("You can't open this yet");
    } else {
        jLabelTargaryen.setToolTipText("");
    }
}
```

It says that void cannot be converted to boolean but I can't modify the event anymore beacuse it is Java Swing.

Comment: `setEnabled` doesn't return a `boolean` , you can't use it as a condition. Maybe you meant to call `isEnabled()` instead.

Comment: YES! Thank you so much sir :D